# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\frac{n}{n+2}\bigr)^n$

Tags: limits

I need to determine if the following sum is convergent or divergent.$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(\frac{n}{n+2}\bigr)^{n^2}$$

I proceeded using the simplified root test but i'm stuck here
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\frac{n}{n+2}\bigr)^n$$
I considered using the euler factorisation but it just doesn't work out.

Comment: In the first expression, there is an exponent $n^2$ but it became $n$ in the second. It is normal ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I already applied the root test but i didn't explicitly right the intermediary steps. that's the reason for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left(\dfrac n{n+2}\right)^n=\left(1+\dfrac2n\right)^{-n} =\left[\left(1+\dfrac2n\right)^{n/2}\right]^{-2}$$

Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac2n\right)^{n/2}=e$

Comment: Damn! wow that totally slipped pass me. Thanks so much!